# How do I avoid creating a temporary vector in C++?

Tags: c++

In the following minimal example, `v1` and `v2` and slices of vector `v` and these slices are elements of other vector `vv`.

```
#include<vector>

int main(){
 std::vector<int> v{0,1,2,3,4,5};
 std::vector<int> v1(v.begin(), v.begin() + 2);
 std::vector<int> v2(v.begin() + 2, v.end());

 std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv(2);
 vv[0] = v1;
 vv[1] = v2;

}
```

Is it possible to directly assign slices of `v` to `vv` without creating `v1` and `v2` explicitly?

Comment: Is `vv` supposed to own the slices from `v`, or just a container of all the different slices to make it easier to manage?

Comment: Btw, you might move the temporaries instead of copy: `vv[0] = std::move(v1);`

Comment: @NathanOliver, `vv` owns slices of `v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`vector::assign()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign), eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v{0,1,2,3,4,5};

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv(2);
    vv[0].assign(v.begin(), v.begin() + 2);
    vv[1].assign(v.begin() + 2, v.end());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also pass them to the constructor.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{ 0,1,2,3,4,5 };

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v3 {
            { v.begin(), v.begin() + 2},
            { v.begin() + 2, v.end() }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could emplace them

```
#include<vector>

int main(){
 std::vector<int> v{0,1,2,3,4,5};

 std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv;
 // vv.reserve(2);
 vv.emplace_back(v.begin(), v.begin() + 2);
 vv.emplace_back(v.begin() + 2, v.end());
}
```